# Update argparse namespace with other namespace/dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, argparse

Let's say I have two argparse namespaces

```
parser1 = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser1.add_argument('--name', type=str, required=False, default='John')

args1 = parser1.parse_args()

parser2 = argparse.ArgumentParser(argument_default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
parser2.add_argument('--name', type=str, required=False)

args2 = parser2.parse_args()
```

How can I update `args1` with `args2`? I am aware of updating dicts, i.e.

```
dict = {'name': 'Pete'}
dict.update(**vars(args2))
```

This should work I think (not tested), but can you also update an argparse namespace with another namespace? I would be fine with converting `args2` to a dict to be able to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `subparser` Action class, `argparse.py` uses:

```
    subnamespace, arg_strings = parser.parse_known_args(arg_strings, None)
    for key, value in vars(subnamespace).items():
        setattr(namespace, key, value)
```

to copy update `namespace` with values from `subnamespace`.  `argparse` uses the generic `setattr` to set values, minimizing assumptions about valid names.

You might also be able to use

```
 namespace.__dict__.update(subnamespace.__dict__)
```

but I haven't tested it.

Comment: this is basically what I ended up doing, thanks!