# How to add groups in subparser?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I would like to add groups in a subparser.

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="A Pipeline.")
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(
    help="Choose imagery source", dest="imagery_source"
)

animal_parser = subparsers.add_parser("animal")
group1_parser = animal_parser.add_argument_group("for_dog_config")
group1_parser.add_argument("--dog", type=str)

group2_parser = animal_parser.add_argument_group("for_cat_config")
group2_parser.add_argument("--cat", type=str)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

`run_pipeline animal --dog hello --cat world`
Here is the output of namespace.

```
Namespace(cat='world', dog='hello', imagery_source='animal')
```

What I would like is that the `cat` and `dog` are in different namespaces or dictionaries respectively. Is it possible?
Note: I know there are other answers using `add_argument_group` in `ArgumentParser` object, but I need to use `subparsers = prser.add_subparsers` here.

=========== Update ===========
This code block almost do what I need.

```
def get_arg(parser):
    args = parser.parse_args()
    args_groups = {}
    for group in parser._action_groups:
        group_dict = {a.dest: getattr(args, a.dest, None) for a in group._group_actions}
        args_groups.update({group.title: argparse.Namespace(**group_dict)})
    return args_groups

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="A Pipeline.")
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(
    help="Choose imagery source", dest="imagery_source"
)
group1_parser = parser.add_argument_group("for_dog_config")
group1_parser.add_argument("--dog", type=str)

group2_parser = parser.add_argument_group("for_cat_config")
group2_parser.add_argument("--cat", type=str)

args = get_arg(parser)
print(args)
```

Execute `run_stereo_pipeline --dog hello --cat world`
The output is

```
{'positional arguments': Namespace(imagery_source=None), 'optional arguments': Namespace(help=None), 'for_dog_config': Namespace(dog='hello'), 'for_cat_config': Namespace(cat='world')}
```

As you can see, now I can do things like `args["for_cat_config"]` to get all arguments in the `"for_cat_config"` group. But in this approach, I can not specify `animal` source which is what I want in the question.

Comment: `add_argument_group` for  `animal_parser` works the same as for `parser`.  `subparsers` is a special `Action` object, but `animal_parser` is a parser, just like the main.  That said, argument_groups only group the help lines; they don't affect parsing.

Comment: What other answers do you have in mind?  I have explored creating subdirectories or namespaces within in the main namespace, but it requires some special games with the `argparse.Namespace` class, or with the argument `Action` subclass.  I don't `argument_groups` help with that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66831906/update-argparse-namespace-with-other-namespace-dictionary explains the relation between the subparser's namespace and the main parser's - values are just copied from one to the other.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884513/python-argparse-how-can-i-get-namespace-objects-for-argument-groups-separately - an example of how convoluted it is to create separate namespace objects.  Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668227/argparse-subcommands-with-nested-namespaces

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for your reply. But I have read through the link you provide which does not really help in my case, unfortunately. Btw, I update my question. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to  look in `animal_parser._action_groups`.  `parser` doesn't have access to the groups in the other parsers.  Or you could have a separate list or dict of `dest` that you want to group separately.  Using `_action_groups` for this purpose might be more work than it's worth.  This regrouping is outside of the `argparse` proper, so can be done in whatever way is programmatically convenient.